# Complex integration $\int_{C(0,1)}(2z-3)\cos5zdz$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

The following complex integration question has me stuck...

$$\int_{C(0,1)}(2z-3)\cos5zdz$$

So I wondered is there a way of applying a theorem to quickly solve this or should I look at integration by parts?

Perhaps $\cos(5z)$ being an entire function could be applied somewhere.

Or should I look at the root of $(2z-3)$ which is $z=\frac{3}{2}$

But $\frac{3}{2}$ is not $\in D(0,1+\epsilon)$ which means the integral is $0$

All help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A holomorphic\analytic function's integral on a closed circut is 0. (one of Cauchy's theorem I believe)
Since your function is analytic as a product of two analytic functions, the integral is 0.